# Java starting and seeking a video using a custom java File System abstraction

Tags: java, javafx, video, filesystems, vlcj

I have a custom Java NIO *FileSystem*. I have to validate it's usability for video playing, seeking, etc. in a demo.

My problem is that I cannot find any library which allows me to play a video from anything other
than a regular File or URL. I tried with *vlcj*, *javafx* with no luck.

My question is what library should I use for starting a video from a custom *FileSystem* abstraction?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LibVLC has support for in-memory stream playback.

This should get you started for Java (credit to caprica)

https://gist.github.com/caprica/52b1793500626cdc88d756175cf9aa4c